# Unable to click textbox with negative z-index

Tags: css, z-index

I have a textbox in the middle of the screen, but when I click on it, no clicks are registered. I think it's a CSS Z-Index issue.  How do I go about diagnosing and fixing this issue?

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jbutler483/uqdukbek/4/)

```css
div#container {
    z-index:-1;
    position:relative;
    height:300px;
    width:300px;
    margin:0 auto;
    background-color: #E9E9E9;
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
    padding-top: 8px;
}
h2 {
    text-align:center;
}
#container input[type="submit"] {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    height:50px;
    width:100%;
}
#container input[type="text"], #container input[type="password"] {
    position:absolute;
    outline:0;
    border:none;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    height:50px;
    top:50px;
    width:100%;
}
#container input[type="password"] {
    top:150px;
}
.overlay {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    z-index:2;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    background:gray;
    text-align:center;
    line-height:300px;
    box-shadow:inset 0 120px 0 0 darkgray, inset 0 122px 0 0 gray, inset 0 124px 0 0 darkgray, inset 0 -120px 0 0 darkgray, inset 0 -122px 0 0 gray, inset 0 -124px 0 0 darkgray;
}
body:hover .overlay {
    display:none;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
     <h2>LOGIN</h2>

    <input type="text" id="name" placeholder="Enter your Name" />
    <input type="password" id="password" placeholder="Enter your Password" />
    <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Login" />
    <div class="overlay">LOGIN HERE</div>
</div>
```

My issue is that I can't actually click on the inputs. I have tried playing around with the layout, but I can't seem to get the inputs 'clickable'.

Could someone explain how this issue could be resolved?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The issue is with the `z-index` property of `div#container` element assigned as  -1.

Set the z-index for the element to some higher value like 1000 etc.

```
div#container {

    background-color: #E9E9E9;
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
    clear: left;
    height: 75px;
    margin: 0 auto 13px;
    overflow: auto;
    padding-top: 8px;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    width: 510px;
    z-index: 1000;
}
```

Answer (score 12):

Z-index should be used when layering actual elements on top of/behind other elements, and shouldn't  really be given a negative value for inputs - especially when your body element (I believe) will be defaulted to 0.

This means that setting a value below 0 (i.e. a negative value), would mean that your element would be placed **behind the body**.

So, if this was an input element, you couldn't actually click on it as *'you would be clicking on the body instead'*, and not actually the input.

---

In the rare occasions that you would place a z-index on an input (most of the time you don't really need to declare one), rather than setting a negative value, try using a low positive value instead. That way it *should* be above the body (unless this has been changed).

Here is a short example:

```css
body {
  background: tomato;
}
input {
  z-index: -2;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="i'm unclickable!" />
```

---

By using a positive value (0 or greater), you can then select the textbox

```css
body{
  background:tomato;
  }
input{
  position:relative;
  z-index:0;
  }
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="i'm now clickable!"/>
```

In the above example, you could ultimately remove the z-index altogether.

For more information on the `z-index` property, please refer to its [documentation](https://www.w3.org/community/webed/wiki/CSS/Properties/z-index)

---

## [JsFiddle Solution](http://jsfiddle.net/jbutler483/uqdukbek/5/)